# What does the keyword this refer to in this context?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, this, semantic-ui

I  am using jQuery and semantic UI for a project, and I got stuck with what the second `this` is referring to. what would the second this be referring to? I am new with jQuery by the way. I want the second this to refer to `#sideBar` a but every time I try to add classes it doesn't work,

I want to remove all classes, then add item to all of them, then get the text content of the anchor tag and set that anchor tag's attribute with a class with the textContent as it's name.

```
$('#sideBar a').on('click', function(){
    $('#sideBar a').removeClass().addClass("item");
    var addC = ($(this).text());
    $(this).addClass(addC);
});
```

Could anyone tell me how to do this, I have some knowledge of apply call and bind in javascript by the way

Comment: It will refer to the exact same thing the first `this` refers to, the `#sidebar a` element that was clicked on.

Answer (score 2):

`this` inside and event listener with a non-arrow function will be your event target:

```
$('#sideBar a').on('click', function (event) {
    // next line removes all classes from all anchor elements that are children of #sideBar then adds the class item to each of them
    $('#sideBar a').removeClass().addClass("item");
    // sets addC to whatever the event target's text is
    var addC = ($(this).text());
    // adds the text stored in addC as a class to the event target
    $(this).addClass(addC);

    console.log(this === event.target); // logs true

});
```

edit: I just realized I didn't answer your question:

`$(this).parents('#sideBar').first().addClass(addC);` instead of `$(this).addClass(addC);` should do the trick.

Comment: This code works, thanks. But could you explain to me the difference  between my original non-working code and your code and why yours works and my code didnt?

Comment: You want to add the class to the `#sideBar` element. In the event handler, `event.target` is a child of `#sideBar`, so we go back up the tree with `.parents('#sideBar')` and grab the first one, then add the class to it.